# Maintain 16:9 aspect ratio with height 100%

Tags: css, height, width

I want to give a div a height of 100% while maintaining a 16:9 aspect ratio. Is this possible using CSS.

I’ve seen some examples that have a width of 100% and then use a percentage padding-bottom value. But not sure how to turn it around for a 100% height.

Comment: Interesting challenge. I made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/v3ec4rb4/1/) but it's a bit of a hack; I don't think you'll like it.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a 9:16 ratio? You could do the same thing as the 100% wide examples you've seen but do `width: 0; padding-right: 54%;` (or whatever).

Comment: @Mr Lister, you're a star thanks, works treat.